# How to create separated XML nodes with "set" in Puppet using Augeas?

Tags: xml, set, puppet, augeas

I am using the Augeas tool for Puppet 3.2 and I am trying to create an XML file. I want to be able to add multiple fields with the same name into my XML doc. For instance, I want to separate node2/location2 from node1/location1 by placing it in its own "node" field. This is my code:

```
    augeas { "update template":
        lens    => "Xml.lns",
        require => File["${buildpath}/tempfile.xml"],
        incl => "${buildpath}/tempfile.xml",
        changes => [
            "set member/acceptors[#attribute]/node[#attribute]/nodeIdentity[#attribute]/#text node2",
            "set member/acceptors/node/nodeLocation[#attribute]/#text location2",
            "set member/acceptors/node/nodeIdentity[#attribute]/#text node1",
            "set member/acceptors/node/nodeLocation[#attribute]/#text location1"
        ],
   }
```

This is the XML output that I get:

```
    <member>
        <acceptors>
            <node>
                <nodeIdentity>node2</nodeIdentity>
                <nodeLocation>location2</nodeLocation>
                <nodeIdentity>node1</nodeIdentity>
                <nodeLocation>location1</nodeLocation>
            </node>
        </acceptors>
    </member>
```

This is the output I want:

```
    <member>
        <acceptors>
            <node>
                <nodeIdentity>node2</nodeIdentity>
                <nodeLocation>location2</nodeLocation>
            </node>
            <node>
                <nodeIdentity>node1</nodeIdentity>
                <nodeLocation>location1</nodeLocation>
            </node>
        </acceptors>
    </member>
```

I have tried adding [#attribute] to the node1 line like the following:

```
     "set member/acceptors/node[#attribute]/nodeIdentity[#attribute]/#text node1",
```

But "node1" doesn't get outputted. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have come across this problem and I think `augeas` doesn't support multiple array `[]` in one `set`.

Comment: Oh, really? That's too bad. Is there an easy alternative to accomplishing this?

Comment: I am afraid, there isn't a easy solution to this. You have to use a template and fill in the necessary attributes...

Comment: I will just templates then! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `node` you want to impact with the XPath expression. In your case, you can write an idempotent change by doing this:

```
augeas { "update template":
     lens    => "Xml.lns",
     require => File["${buildpath}/tempfile.xml"],
     incl    => "${buildpath}/tempfile.xml",
     changes => [
         "set member/acceptors/node[nodeIdentity/#text='node2']/nodeIdentity/#text node2",
         "set member/acceptors/node[nodeIdentity/#text='node2']/nodeLocation/#text location2",
         "set member/acceptors/node[nodeIdentity/#text='node1']/nodeIdentity/#text node1",
         "set member/acceptors/node[nodeIdentity/#text='node1']/nodeLocation/#text location1"
     ],
}
```

There is no need (that I see) to filter on the existence of `#attribute` sub-nodes, all the more that you don't create them, so you're changes won't be idempotent.